# How can I automatically generate filenames before saving it in a folder VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I have a program that saves the image file path to the database. The image is then save to a specific folder where it is being retrieved by the file path saved in the database. However, I cannot save an image with the same filename because it is already in the folder.

Here is my code in copying the image into the folder:

```
Private Sub ButtonBrowseImage_Click(sender as System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonBrowseImage.Click

     Dim opf as New OpenFileDialog
     opf.Filter="Choose Image(*.JPG, *.PNG, *.GIF)|*.jpg; *.png; *.gif"

       If opf.ShowDialog=Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ok Then
         If opf.CheckFileExists Then
           Dim paths As String = Application.StartupPath.Substring (0, (Application.StartupPath.Length - 10 ))
           Dim CorrectFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(opf.filename)
           System.IO.File.Copy(opf.FileName, paths + "\\artwork\\" + CorrectFileName)
         End If
       End If
```

Is there any way to automatically generate filename or overwrite the saved image file with the same image but with a different filename?

Comment: First, dont use `Application.StartupPath` - store the data in one of the Users folders, that is what they are for.  Then you could use the original file name from the dialog and prepend the primary key.  If you dont save the Path part to the DB you can move/remap the images folder without updating all the image names. Write a method to create the same file name pattern every time.  Also you should dispose of Dialogs, and parse file names using `Path` not substring.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

To generate random file name, you can use:

```
Path.GetRandomFileName()
```

Here is an example:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim result = Path.GetRandomFileName()
        Console.WriteLine("Random file name is " + result)
    End Sub

End Module

' This code produces output similar to the following:

' Random file name is w143kxnu.idj
' Press any key to continue . . .
```